# Leverage MapKit to render custom image - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, mkmapview, mapkit

Our use case is to display an image to the user which she can maximize/minimize (pinch). Also, there are specific points (Options) on the image which user can click. In case user decides to maximize the image then the points will also increase in size in proportion.

I have been exploring MapKit. Well, MapKit is extremely convenient to use because it provides all these functionalities - I can identify the touch and I don't have to worry about the user pinching the image.

I am wondering if it is possible to paste an image (probably the image of a human body) over this mapView without showing the map! Its like a quiz - where the user needs to click on the head.

Code to display the map:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit
@objc public class MTMapViewController : MTAbstractQuizController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
}
```

I am just exploring if mapView can be used to resolve my use case.

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of `iOS11`, `MKMapType` will have a new case, called `mutedStandard`, which will be `A street map where your data is emphasized over the underlying map details.` See the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmaptype/2875426-mutedstandard).

I haven't tried this myself, but it seems like a suitable candidate for your problem.

Comment: Does that mean instead of displaying a map, I can display an image of my own, like a shoe, a dress or maybe a bottle? At the same time, I will be able to add annotations, pinch it, etc?

Comment: As I've already mentioned, I haven't tried this method myself, so I cannot be sure. You can install Xcode9 beta and test it yourself. Sadly the documentation of it is quite vague, so just based on that it is hard to say anything certain.

Comment: Cool. Let me try that. Will let you know if it works!